# Transformation function for matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, transformation

I have 2 matrices in Matlab, `A` and `B`, I am trying to find an easy way to take these in and output a function that maps `A` to `B`, it should be as easy as a function in the form of `B=Ax+y` where `x` and `y` are static numbers, but I cannot seem to remember my basic math skills today. Is there an easy way of doing this in Matlab?

Comment: To clarify: You are given two matrices A and B, and want to find two scalars x and y that will satisfy B=Ax+y (in some cases there can be no such x and y)? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*

This is the answer to the OP's original question as explained in the comments.

Take two elements `b1` and `b2` from `B` and the same elements `a1` and `a2` from `A`. Be sure that `a1 ~= a2`. If all elements of `A` are the same then the problem is trivial. Then compute

```
x = (b1-b2) / (a1-a2) ;
y = b1 - a1*x;
err = B - A*x - y;
total_error = sum(abs(err(:)));
```

If `x` and `y` do not satisfy the equation, then `total_error > 0` and there is no such `x` and `y`.

---

Actually, if x and y are just numbers, you can just do

```
B = A*x + y;
```

Matlab is capable of doing matrix times scalar arithmetic by broadcasting the number `x` to each element of `A`.

If `x` is a vector and `A*x` makes sense, you can do the same.

If `y` is a scalar or a vector of the same size as `A*x`, you can also do the same.

Comment: But my issue is that I do not know x or y, I need to figure them out from A and B

Comment: Just to clarify, are A and B n by m matrices while x and y are scalars?

Comment: Correct, A and B are n by n matrices and x and y are scalar doubles.